# How can I test whether a file has been opened for writing in Perl?

Tags: perl, file

In my apps, I need to check whether a given file has been opened for writing for another process, and even this file has been opened my app just skip this file and no "die"-like things will happen here.

---

more detailed description of my problem:

there are two process involved. process A , which is the producer process, process B which is the consumer processw.

process A will create some requests for B to handle and the way he creates request is just create a txt-based  file under a certain directory. when A create the request, he dose not know whether B is alive or not, what he needs to do is just drop the request, kind of like write a email to B. after create the request file, A will never visite it again.

prpcess B , is sometime up and sometime down. when it is running, B will "spool" the directory which A drop reqeusts. for each requst file, B just read it hand it and remove it.

but I think there is some race condition there. For example, A just open a file and is on the way of filling up the file with a request and then B want to read the same file and hand
it.

my question is how should I hand the race condition gracefully in perl ?

Comment: We need to know which OS you're running on

Comment: Do you want to know if it is currently open, or has been modified recently?

Comment: Annoying problem to solve on most operating systems.  Tell us what you're trying to accomplish and we can probably come up with a better plan.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the update on your problem. Here's how I would do it:

- Process A opens a temporary file and writes to it. You name the file in such a way that Process B ignores it. You can do that by having it in a temp directory, using a suffix that B doesn't process, or whatever.
- When A is done, it closes the file. The file is now complete, but has the temporary name.
- A renames the file to its final name, which B recognizes as something it needs to process.
- B processes the file.

---

From my previous answer, now explained in the question:

This sounds like a suspicious strategy. Suppose, for instance, that Process A opens File 1 for writing and starts working with it. Process B starts up and considers processing File 1 too. Should it skip it? What if Process A closes the file before Process B can determine if it is open? Should Process B process File 1 again?

It sounds like you have an [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341) where you are giving us what you think the solution is but not telling us about the problem or task. What are you trying to accomplish or avoid? Something like:

- The same program has many instances processing many files in parallel for the same purpose
- Different programs running simultaneously have to process the same files for different purposes, perhaps in sequence
- The same program might have many instances but only one should update the file (i.e. two people each try to update the same file at the same time).
- Some other situation

Tell us what you are doing and we might be able to solve your problem instead of merely answering your question. :)

Comment: a more detailed description of my problem has been added , then It's your guys time to write down your wisdom.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which OS you're running on. If Unix (or a derivative), take a look at [lsof](http://www.physiol.ox.ac.uk/Computing/Online_Documentation/lsof-quickstart.txt). This will tell you (amongst other things) what files are opened, by whom etc.

Man page [here](http://www.netadmintools.com/html/lsof.man.html). Note the -F option, which outputs in a fashion suitable for other programs to parse.

Comment: the app will run on linux. I'll check lsof first. thank a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Supplementing Brian Agnew's answer: if you would like to use lsof check out Unix::Lsof on CPAN, which provides a perlish interface to the command.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of thing that file locks are meant to handle, but you probably don't even need to get that low-level. If both ends of the chain are Perl, you should look at using `IPC::DirQueue` to manage the queue; it's pretty well tested and flexible.